# XOpenDisplay(NULL) fails to connect to X

Tags: ssh, cygwin, xserver

I was given a fairly large program to compile and run with extremely vague instructions on how to properly configure my system and install the program.  I was told to use a Windows, install Cygwin, navigate to the program's base directory, and type "make".  I installed Cygwin on a 64-bit Windows 7 in C:\cygwin64 as the main user (I also installed all of the default packages, plus a few extras) and then ran the makefile included with the program (this worked with no problems).  When trying to run the executable with a required file argument, I was simply given the error message "cannot connect to X server."  Upon examination of the code, it appears that this error was caused by a line setting `display=XOpenDisplay(NULL)` and then exiting when this resulted in `display == NULL`.  Earlier, "display" had been declared as a variable of type Display.  Is there any way I can get the program to connect to the X server?  I have been assured that the installation of the program is extremely easy, but I'm not so sure...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the variable `DISPLAY` in your environment?  Usually you just set it to `:0.0` and things will work after that, but Cygwin may be odd in that respect (too). See also [XOpenDisplay(3X)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xopendisplay)

Comment: I had not set up the variable.  I ran `export DISPLAY = :0.0` and also `export DISPLAY = <IP>:0.0`, but these give the same error message, followed by the value in `DISPLAY`.  Is it possible I did not install all the necessary packages in Cygwin?

Comment: Possible, yes. So are you running an X11 server at all?

Comment: No, I do not believe I am.  I have never worked with that before.

Comment: So I guess you'll need to add http://x.cygwin.com/ or something similar.

Comment: However, that's based on assumptions which could be completely wrong in your scenario. We could be wasting your time here. Perhaps you could add more information about your program and the architecture it is supposed to run in.